# PHP : Echo java script code to given url

Tags: javascript, php

I wanted to auto-fill a form on a web page. I wrote the javascript code for that, and it is working fine. When I visit the web page manually and run the JS code in the console, it works. But I need this JS code to be run from a server by a PHP code. So I'd like to `echo` this javascript to the specified URL.

Basically, I want a PHP file on a server (with no browser environment) to run a javascript code on a webpage , using `echo` . I know how to echo HTML/JS from PHP, but I want it to run on a specific web page. Since there is no browser involved I can't use the JS code `window.location.href=url` to do this.

Here's the PHP code to echo the JS:

```
echo "  <html>
    <head>
        <script src="../js/xyz.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="tmp()">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function tmp(){
                // FIRST VISIT THE URL AND THEN RUN BELOW FUNCTION
                someJSfunction("12345","0019");
            }
        </script>"
    </body>
    </html>
    "
;
```

Comment: What did you try yourself yet and can you show us some code?

Comment: You need to escape the quotes.

Comment: yeah, I'll do that. But the central problem is to run this on a particular web page.

Comment: Then I misunderstood the question. Not really sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: If there is no browser involved how is a user supposed to see this webpage? Or are you trying to create something like a bot, one that would auto fill / submit forms on webpages?

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yes, but via PHP

Answer (score -1):

no browser will support cross-site injection. whatever you are trying to do from within a browser and using java script is not possible. 
However, if you are trying to log in to a web site using user/pass and then navigate through or download data. I would suggest using phantomJS or zombi.js using node.js , or WWW::Mechanize using perl, ruby and python also has mechanize modules

if however your login dialog box from the site ,is generated via javascript then you would need a javascript engine e.g.: spydermonkey to process the javascript without have a browser on the server. e.g.: JavaScript::SpiderMonkey